# Kubernetes unable to query kubernetes secret using API

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to query `kubernetes secret` using APIs and  I provided required permission to account `"default:default"` using the following command

```
kubectl create rolebinding default-viewer \
  --clusterrole=view \
  --serviceaccount=default:default \
  --namespace=default
```

I was able to query the pods under namespace "default" using the following command

```
   curl -v -s https://10.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --cacert /tmp/ca.crt
```

However, when I try to get the `secrets` from namespace `"default"` it errored with the following

```
curl -v -s https://10.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --cacert /tmp/ca.crt
```

**ERROR**

```
 "message": "secrets is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot list resource \"secrets\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"",
```

I am not sure what am I missing here?  Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided access to Service account `default` of default namespace using cluster role `view`. It seems(at least in my cluster) like the cluster role `view` does not provide any permissions related to secret.

```
  kubectl describe  clusterrole view |grep -iEw 'secret|pods'
  pods/log                                     []                 []              [get list watch]
  pods/status                                  []                 []              [get list watch]
  pods                                         []                 []              [get list watch]
```

If you run the above command and the output of above command is same, then this explain why you can query `pods` not `secrets`. Below command print the cluster roles having string "secret" in it.

```
kubectl get clusterrole -o name |while read cr; do k describe $cr |grep -q secret && echo "$cr is having secret"; done
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/admin is having secret
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/edit is having secret
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:aggregate-to-edit is having secret
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:expand-controller is having secret
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:persistent-volume-binder is having secret
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:kube-controller-manager is having secret
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:node is having secret
```

You may need to create a new clusterrole/role or modify the existing clusterrole/role.

**Additionally,** You can run the kubectl with `--raw` to validate your API query/URI. This will remove Certificates, keys, cacert and tokens out of the equation. Eg:

```
kubectl get --raw  https://10.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets --as system:serviceaccount:default:default
```